# validate a form which is loaded via AJAX on page

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

how to validate a form which is loaded via `AJAX` on page. i'm using jquery `validate.js`. plugin. i call the validate function after the form is loaded via ajax, but it doesn't work.

jquery code :

```
  $(document.body).on('click', '.submitBtn', function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $("#form"+id).validate({
     submitHandler: function() {

        // do anything

     }
   });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `jquery.validate.js`?

Comment: check console for errors. I think `$("#form"+id)` is not yet available when you run `validate` method on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume you have a `main` page and the ajax form in `ajax` page, looks like you are keeping the code for that form validation in the main page statically. Even before the ajax happens.

So when the `main` page loads, the validation code runs but it does not find the `"#form"+id`(coz it's not loaded yet). Hence event bindings by the plugin fail.

What you can do is to send in the validation script along with your ajax response so that the validation code runs ONLY AFTER you have loaded the form and the events are properly bound.

**OLD AJAX FILE**

```
//contains only the form
```

**NEW AJAX FILE**

```
//contains the form 
//then contains the validation code.
```

**NOTE -** There are other ways to do it. Like using jQuery's `live` method. Quick Googling will give you quite a few results.

Comment: If you look at his code carefully, you will find he's well and truly using delegate(the event originated from .submitBtn is delegated by document.body). So its binding is OK. Look at my answer,

Comment: what if the `id` is a string and it builds a string like "#formTHESTRING" the selector is fine.

Comment: "#formTHESTRING" means an element with an id of "ormTHESTRING". Clearly it's a wrong selector.

Comment: @wander - http://jsfiddle.net/6Pup5/ . You might be thinking `form` is an element selector but in this case, it's just a plain simple string. much like prefix for the `id` var indicating the `id` is for a form element.

Comment: @ShilpiSingh - Glad! Accept the answer when you can! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple syntax error, change `"#form"+id` to `"form#"+id`
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTu4X/).

```
$(document.body).on("click", "form", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("form#" + id).validate({
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert("submit");
        }
    });
});
```

I wonder why do you use this ugly way of selecting element. If the form does not have an id attribute, the selection will fail. I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F52MA/) is better

Comment: this code work properly when form is already loaded. .but not work when form is loaded via ajax on page.

Comment: As you can see the form is dynamically added, not added from startup... Simply replace the append code with ajax.

Comment: @ShilpiSingh - try jQuery `live` as I said, or put the script after the form in the `ajax` response itself.

Comment: @wander - how are you so sure it's a syntax error? It's absolutely fine to have that kind of selector